# How to get the audio to flow as expected when subclassing SPTCoreAudioController

Tags: swift, audio, spotify, core-audio, audio-streaming

I am attempting to override Spotify's SPTCoreAudioController in order to get at the audio buffer so I can do some processing. I was able to subclass it and override the correct function. Just as a baseline, I was attempting to pass through the audioFrames and frameCount back to the audio pipeline by calling super.attempt...() The audio flows as expected however it got sped up after the first few seconds. I was expecting it just to pass through and playback normally.  Can anyone explain why this is happening and/or point me to what I need to learn in order to work with the audio frames that are passed to me?

Here is the code:

```
class CoreAudioController: SPTCoreAudioController {
  override func attempt(toDeliverAudioFrames audioFrames: UnsafeRawPointer!, ofCount frameCount: Int, streamDescription audioDescription: AudioStreamBasicDescription) -> Int {
    print("attempt to deliver audio frames")


      super.attempt(toDeliverAudioFrames: audioFrames, ofCount: frameCount, streamDescription: audioDescription)

    return frameCount
  }

}
```

Here is where I pass the custom controller above to the Spotify AudioStreamingController:

```
 func initializaPlayer(authSession:SPTSession){
  if self.player == nil {

      self.audioController = CoreAudioController()

      self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
      self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
      self.player!.delegate = self
      try! self.player?.start(withClientId: auth?.clientID, audioController: self.audioController, allowCaching: false)
      //try! player?.start(withClientId: auth?.clientID)
      self.player!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)

  }
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't that be `return super.attempt(...)`?

Comment: Oh man!  That's it.  Thank you so much.  If you make a formal answer I can approve it.  Thanks again!